# Firefox : TypeError: Components.classes[cid] is undefined

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am creating my own add-on for FireFox. 
In FF 21 it works fine but with FF 22 I am getting error: **TypeError: Components.classes[cid] is undefined.** I've integrated my add-on with gecko sdk 22, 
so I have no idea why it dosent works in 22.

It is also giving error while loading dll here is the error. **Failed to load native module at path : (80004003) error 126**

Comment: Can you please post some more code for community to be able to help you?

Answer (score 0):

You should do `require('chrome').Cc[cid]`

Comment: Hi erikvold  thanks for reply after adding this line it is giving error **require is undefind.**

Comment: Hi erikvold  thanks for reply  Yes I am using gecko-sdk 22 here is the may code    **var compClass = Components.classes["@xyz.com/NIKXPCOM;1"];
var instance = compClass.createInstance();** I am getting error at **var instance = compClass.createInstance();** this code was working fine for gecko-sdk 21. I have recompiled the code with gecko-sdk 22.

Comment: in what context are you running your code? because in the normal `main.js` context my example will work..

Comment: Yes I am running doe in main.js context this code is working fine on FF 21 bt FF 22 it is giving error.